# Why the model gradients are not computed?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am new in Pytorch and I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem via Pytorch: I'm playing the game Rock paper scissors

We are two players

J1 Rock - J2 Rock : 0$

J1 Rock - J2 Paper : -1$

J1 Rock - J2 Scissors : 2$

J1 Paper - J2 Scissors : -1$

And the opposite. In brief, if I win with Rock, I win 2$ instead of 1$

I am trying to make play 2 machines in this game to find out what will be the optimal distribution of choices between Rock/Paper/Scissors. Here is my code in Pytorch

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Modele(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Modele, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 5)  
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 3)  
        
    def forward(self,x):
        
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))  
        x = self.fc2(x)  
        return x


model1 = Modele()
model2 = Modele()




def discrete_loss(x,y):

    discrete_loss = (x == y)*torch.tensor(0.) +\
                    ((x==1)&(y==0))*torch.tensor(1.) +\
                    ((x==0)&(y==1))*torch.tensor(-1.)+\
                    ((x==0)&(y==2))*torch.tensor(2.)+\
                    ((x==2)&(y==0))*torch.tensor(-2.)+\
                    ((x==1)&(y==2))*torch.tensor(-1.) +\
                    ((x==2)&(y==1))*torch.tensor(1.)         
    return discrete_loss.sum().float() 

optimizer1 = optim.SGD(model1.parameters(), lr=0.001)
optimizer2 = optim.SGD(model2.parameters(), lr=0.001)

n =  5
for i in range(10) : 
    optimizer1.zero_grad()
    optimizer2.zero_grad()
    x = torch.rand(n,1,requires_grad=True)
    y = torch.rand(n,1, requires_grad=True)
    x = model1(x)
    y = model2(y)
    x = torch.argmax(x, dim=1)
    y = torch.argmax(y, dim=1)
    
    
    loss1 = -discrete_loss(x,y)
    loss1.requires_grad = True
    loss1.backward()
    optimizer1.step()
    print(loss1.grad)

    optimizer2.zero_grad()
    loss2 = discrete_loss(x,y)
    loss2.requires_grad = True
    loss2.backward()
    optimizer2.step()
```

I generate a random number between 0 and 1 which will correspond after entering the model to 0 (Rock), 1 (Paper) or 2 (Scissors).
But the model does not work. First I used a discrete loss and I don't know if it works and moreover, during the backward, my parameters are not updated.... If you have a solution it would help me a lot to understand how Pytorch works !

Answer (score 2):

The gradient is calculated correctly, but the reason your model can't learn is that your loss function has a gradient of zero at most points. Descending a loss function is like rolling a ball down a hill, and a ball can't roll down a hill when there is no hill to begin with. You'll need to come up with a smooth loss function, creating a landscape for the ball to roll down.

[image: discrete rock paper scissors loss]

Here's what generates the 3D image of your loss function:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import torch

def discrete_loss(x, y):
    return (x == y)*torch.tensor(0.) +\
           ((x==1)&(y==0))*torch.tensor(1.) +\
           ((x==0)&(y==1))*torch.tensor(-1.)+\
           ((x==0)&(y==2))*torch.tensor(2.)+\
           ((x==2)&(y==0))*torch.tensor(-2.)+\
           ((x==1)&(y==2))*torch.tensor(-1.) +\
           ((x==2)&(y==1))*torch.tensor(1.)

x = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

x_torch = torch.from_numpy(x)
y_torch = torch.from_numpy(y)

z = discrete_loss(x_torch, y_torch)

z = z.numpy()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Discrete Loss')

plt.show()
```

Best of luck on your `pytorch` journey.

Comment: thank you for your comment, do you have an idea to how make this loss smoother?

Comment: @badinmaths Hmm not sure right off the bat  Well, let's consider the conditional `(x==1)&(y==0)`. If `x == 1` and `y == 0`, then it outputs `1`, else it outputs `0`, so we're looking for a smooth function that's close to that. So as `x` drifts away from `1`, and as `y` drifts away from `0`, our loss should increase. `torch.abs(x - 1) + torch.abs(y - 0)` maybe? From there, you may want to use `torch.pow(x - 1, 2) + torch.pow(y - 0, 2)` instead of `abs`, that might create a less jagged landscape, as `abs` is pointy and not differentiable at `abs(0)`.

Comment: @badinmaths Also np